# Cannot understand this line of javascript code

Tags: javascript

```
    let tempProducts = [];
storeProducts.forEach((item) => {
  const singleItem = { ...item };
  tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem]; <----- This Line
});
```

What does the above indicated line mean? It looks like new ES6 syntax, but unlike anything I have seen before. Can anyone explain this to me please?

Answer (score -1):

It creates a new array which consists of the items from `tempProducts` and the `singleItem`.

It has the same result as

```
tempProducts.concat(singleItem);
```

The (quite modern) syntax with the three dots is called 'spreading', the `...` is the spread operator.